# I can't ask questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, post-ban

My SO account has been blocked from asking questions. This has been for a while now. I have a reputation of 139. I have a single downvote on a question and the question is closed as "closed as primarily opinion-based". I think I had a duplicate of the question and I had deleted it. Though I don't see that question in my profile anymore.

Would be really great if some of the admins could enable my account or atleast let me know what all I can do (improving the question or more better acts haven't helped so far).

My SO profile - https://stackoverflow.com/users/1675384/anshu-prateek

As to the folks marking this as duplicate - yes, I have read the links, and have tried to follow up on them. I have asked this question after my attempts were not successful, i.e, specific to my scenario where deleted questions are still impacting my ability to ask question. Also, @George Stocker has been kind enough to specifically answer my scenario, so I guess, this question is not a duplicate of generic question.

Comment: Did you follow the link ?

Comment: Yes, I have. My guess is am still in blocked condition due to the deleted question. I can no longer see the deleted question, so can't improve it. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have three deleted questions:

- [Puppet cert list all using API Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820217/puppet-cert-list-all-using-api-python)
- [How does 0.0.0.0 binding happen in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397936/how-does-0-0-0-0-binding-happen-in-linux)
- [Share content from device browser through facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445726/share-content-from-device-browser-through-facebook-app)

You have two undeleted questions, one of which has negative votes (this affects your ability to post new questions)

- [Python better way to pass function return to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479620/python-better-way-to-pass-function-return-to-another-function)

Since you now have the link, spend some time and improve those posts and then flag them for undeletion. I'll go into greater detail about the problem with those questions below.

You deleted the first question, "Puppet cert list all using API/Python", even though you got a valuable answer to it.  Why did you delete this question?  You could improve the question and flag it for undeletion.  By deleting it, you're effectively cutting yourself off from being able to improve it, but the negative effects of the downvotes are still there.

Second question: "How does 0.0.0.0 binding happen in linux?" is way off topic for Stack Overflow. To the point of, "Why did you think this question belonged on Stack overflow?" It's also a broadly written question (how does network binding work in Linux?) and it's got grammatical and spelling issues that kept it from ever being a good migration candidate.

Your third deleted question: "Share content from device browser through Facebook App" is a bit broad as well and it smells like a "Do this for me" question. The community doesn't respond very well to those types of questions.

If you have a *specific* issue you're trying to solve, show us the code related to it, and what doesn't work about that code.

For "Python better way to pass function return to another function", it has a few issues:

Stack Overflow isn't really meant for "Hey, I like this code style, but is this other code style "better"? We don't do well with subjective issues like Tabs vs. Spaces, code styles, formatting, or just general things that differ depending on what side of the bed you woke up on.

If you can show us the science, or put some data into it, like "This version of the return statement executes 100x faster on my PC (here's my benchmarking data). Why does it execute 100x faster?"  That has a concrete answer that is objectively correct. We're good at that.  For your sanity, and for the sanity of those around you, keep style questions out of Stack Overflow.  Unless you have a high reputation or you hit the Hacker News lottery, your question will be downvoted and closed.

Some general pointers:

- Don't come to Stack Overflow to get information. Go to google for that. Come to Stack Overflow when you have a specific programming problem that you need solved and you have something concrete to show us.
- Read through the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its related links (in fact, just read every link on that page). That'll help you determine what sorts of questions do well here, and what do not.
- Do some searching on Stack Overflow. Check out posts that have votes greater than 1 but less than 20 and that were asked within the last 6 months.  See what those questions look like, and try to emulate the style those questions take.
- Pay special attention to grammar and spelling of your post and making your title something "searchable".  Even though your questions were downvoted, for the most part they have good titles. Keep that up.

Related: [Show all of my questions/answers, even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/170487#170487)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Let me try and answer these a bit since I already have a -1 even on this question.

Comment: Yup, and if they have used another editor to have an improved version ready in the meantime, you can then just paste in the new version.

Comment: @George Stocker well I remember that the first question delete was a panic response to a downvote or a ban on asking questions. I have undeleted it now and am looking into them. As to the second question, I came to know about SU through the comment. As to grammatical and spell errors, I am still dumbfounded about which errors are there in there. As to the third one, yes, the performance impact was what I was looking for, but guess I will have to run those and come back with better edit to that question.

Comment: I can post questions on SO again! Thank you @George Stocker and everyone else who answered and helped.